# Liferay 6.2 on JBoss 7.2

Tags: liferay, jboss7.x

I've got a problem. I'm trying to run Liferay 6.2 on my JBoss 7.2. I followed the installation steps (https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/installing-liferay-on-jboss-7-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-15-en) but I'm not able to deploy/start liferay. I'm getting HornetQ exceptions all the time.

```
17:28:17,271 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-9) HQ221004: HornetQ Server version 2.3.0.CR1 (buzzzzz!, 122) [fa28bdb6-0fc3-11e3-ad50-a3678588ef85] stopped
17:30:25,437 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) HQ122018: Can not connect to XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=8e623d60-82ae-11e3-847c-e5da1aae7895, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null] on auto-generated resource recovery: HornetQException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119026: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at [...]
17:30:25,440 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) HQ122010: XA Recovery can not connect to any hornetq server on recovery [XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=8e623d60-82ae-11e3-847c-e5da1aae7895, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null]]
17:30:25,442 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Error trying to connect to any providers for xa recovery
    at [...]
Caused by: HornetQException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=null]
    at [...]
    ... 7 more
17:30:25,443 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) HQ122018: Can not connect to XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=8e623d60-82ae-11e3-847c-e5da1aae7895, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null] on auto-generated resource recovery: HornetQException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119026: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at [...]
17:30:25,444 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) HQ122010: XA Recovery can not connect to any hornetq server on recovery [XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=8e623d60-82ae-11e3-847c-e5da1aae7895, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null]]
17:30:25,444 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) HQ122018: Can not connect to XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=8e623d60-82ae-11e3-847c-e5da1aae7895, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null] on auto-generated resource recovery: HornetQException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119026: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at [...]
17:30:25,445 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) HQ122010: XA Recovery can not connect to any hornetq server on recovery [XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=8e623d60-82ae-11e3-847c-e5da1aae7895, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null]]
17:30:25,446 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) HQ122018: Can not connect to XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=8e623d60-82ae-11e3-847c-e5da1aae7895, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null] on auto-generated resource recovery: HornetQException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119026: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at [...]
17:30:25,447 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) HQ122010: XA Recovery can not connect to any hornetq server on recovery [XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=8e623d60-82ae-11e3-847c-e5da1aae7895, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null]]
17:30:25,447 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Error trying to connect to any providers for xa recovery
    at [...]
Caused by: HornetQException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=null]
    at [...]
    ... 7 more
```

I know Liferay 6.2 is certified against JBoss 7.1, not 7.2 but I already had Liferay 6.1.2 CE running on JBoss 7.2 so I guess there must be a way for 6.2 EE as well.

Does anybody have an idea or can help me out?

Thy and regards
Sebastian

---

I did some changes to my JBoss config. Moved all Liferay-specific settings from full-ha profile to ha profile (no hornetq in ha). So there are no hornetq errors any more. But still I'm not able to deploy Liferay to my JBoss. Server tries to deploy Liferay but (seems to) stop progressing/working without any further information.

```
16:12:51,691 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final "Janus" started in 7662ms - Started 164 of 277 services (112 services are passive or on-demand)
16:17:13,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-30) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "liferay-portal-6.2.10.1-ee-ga1.war" (runtime-name: "liferay.war")
16:17:33,174 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxws-api.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,174 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr181-api.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,174 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr250-api.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,175 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_api.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,175 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry sjsxp.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,175 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry woodstox.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,176 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry resolver.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,176 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,176 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,177 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry stax-utils.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,180 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry unoloader.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jurt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,181 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry ../../lib/ in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jurt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,181 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry ../bin/ in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jurt.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,181 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-impl.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,188 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry lib/ant.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/truezip.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,189 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry lib/lcrypto-jdk14-135.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/truezip.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,196 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,197 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,197 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,197 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,200 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry asm-3.3.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/asm-xml.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,201 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry asm-util-3.3.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/asm-xml.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,201 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry asm-attrs-3.3.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/asm-xml.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,202 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/c3p0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,212 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-cli.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/xuggle-xuggler-noarch.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,212 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry logback-classic.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/xuggle-xuggler-noarch.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,213 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry logback-core.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/xuggle-xuggler-noarch.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,214 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jakarta-oro.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,215 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxp-api.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,216 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jax-qname.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,216 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,216 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015960: Class Path entry servlet.jar in /content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:17:33,553 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
16:17:33,554 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'DRIVER=TRUE' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,554 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'DEFAULT=ear|jar|war|zip' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,554 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'zip=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.zip.ZipDriver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,555 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'ear|jar|war=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.zip.JarDriver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,555 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'odg|odp|ods|odt=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.zip.OdfDriver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,555 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'otg|otp|ots|ott=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.zip.OdfDriver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,555 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'odb|odf|odm|oth=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.zip.OdfDriver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,555 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'exe=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.zip.ReadOnlySfxDriver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,556 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'tzp|zip.rae|zip.raes=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.zip.raes.SafeZipRaesDriver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,556 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'tar=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.tar.TarDriver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,556 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'tgz|tar.gz=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.tar.TarGZipDriver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,556 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'tbz2|tar.bz2=de.schlichtherle.io.archive.tar.TarBZip2Driver' for service type 'de.schlichtherle.io.registry.properties'
16:17:33,559 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser,org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
16:17:33,583 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-25) JBAS015897: Could not find Extension-List entry ExtensionListEntry [name=javax.crypto, title=crypto] referenced from ResourceRoot [root="/content/liferay.war/WEB-INF/classes"]
16:17:36,766 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) JBAS018210: Register web context: 
16:17:37,886 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
16:18:03,800 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) JBAS018224: Unregister web context: /JvmMonitor
16:18:03,834 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWEB003075: Coyote HTTP/1.1 pausing on: http-/10.173.121.39:8380
16:18:03,843 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWEB003077: Coyote HTTP/1.1 stopping on : http-/10.173.121.39:8380
16:18:03,877 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/LIFERAY_TEST_DS]
16:18:03,883 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp] (MSC service thread 1-31) JBWEB003048: Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-/10.173.121.39:8309
16:18:03,884 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp] (MSC service thread 1-31) JBWEB003051: Stopping Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-/10.173.121.39:8309
16:18:03,937 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-24) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment JvmMonitor.war (runtime-name: JvmMonitor.war) in 150ms
```

And thats it ...

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is liferay stopping hornetq during deployment. My other webapps don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my issues. If you intend to run Liferay 6.2 on JBoss 7.2 make sure you're using the same version of liferay.war and liferay-dependencies. Even minor differences result in a crippled JBoss Node. Sadly the logfiles don't offer much information about this other than indicating that something might be wrong.